# Optimizing itertools permutations in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x

In context of memory management i face a lot of issues while using `itertools permutations` specially when the length of list is more than 10.

Is there any better way of generating permutations for any list such that memory is not much utilized ?

Below is the way how i am using it.

```
     num_list = [i for i in range(0,18)]
     permutation_list = list(permutations(num_list,len(num_list)))

     for p_tuples in permutation_list:
          print(p_tuples)
```

Comment: How are you using it?  It won't generate all the permutations at once unless you try to use them all at once.  If you do want to use them all at once, you can't avoid using a fair amount of memory, because the number of permutations is large.

Comment: Why do you have a list? Use them one at a time.

Comment: Can you show us how you're using that function?

Comment: `11!` = `39,916,800`

Comment: I have a list of number in range(0,18). I am generating the permutations and storing it in a list later on which i iterate. (also updated the same in que)

Comment: "storing it in a list" Found your problem.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to use a list comprehension to turn an iterable into a list. You can just pass the iterable to the list constructor, eg `num_list = list(range(18))`. However, even that's unnecessary here, since [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?itertools.permutations#itertools.permutations) will accept an arbitrary iterable as its first argument.

Comment: Why do you need so many permutations? Does order matter?

Answer (score 2):

If all you need to do is iterate over the permutations, don't store them.  Iterate directly over the object returned by `itertools.permutations`.  In other words do this:

```
permutations = permutations(num_list,len(num_list))
for perm in permutations:
    doSomethingWith(perm)
```

Calling `list` on an iterator is exactly the way to say "give me all of the elements right now in memory at the same time".  If you don't want or need all of them in memory at once, don't use `list`.  If you just want to use one element at a time, just iterate over what you want to iterate over.

Note that your code will still take a long time to run if you really try to go through all the permutations, because 18! is a really big number.

Comment: yes, it is still not working (process is taking too much time) but at-least now it is not throwing compilation error of memory limit.

Comment: @CbK: You have a f*ckton of results, so naturally it will take a long time.

Comment: @CbK: You can't expect anything to be fast with 6 quadrillion items to operate on.

Comment: @CbK: What BrenBarn said. FWIW, on my 2GHz machine, `n = 8` `for s in itertools.permutations(range(n), n):` `pass` takes roughly 0.022 seconds, so I estimate that for n=18 it will take about 0.022*18!/8! seconds, which is around 110 _years_.

Answer (score 1):

permutations returns a generator.  So the solution 
is pretty much what you already wrote:

```
num_list = [i for i in range(0,18)]

for p_tuples in permutations(num_list,len(num_list)):
    print(p_tuples)
```